# Compare string to datetime in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, epoch

I've a table with Timestamp column

| timestamp(character varying) |
| --- |
| 1700520221 |
| 1632322404 |

I want to convert these into date time and compare if these are 1 year old and delete them if they're older.

I tried `to_timestamp()` but that doesn't work on tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your numbers are seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, you can very well use [`to_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE) after casting to a numeric type:

```
DELETE FROM tbl
WHERE  to_timestamp(col::float) < now() - interval '1 year';
```

`to_timestamp()` takes `double precision`. Unlike with an untyped literal, an explicit cast is needed for type `varchar`.

If at all possible, convert your `varchar` column to the appropriate type `timestamptz`.